# SQL subquery with reference to parent table gives "Unknown column 'test_results.id' in 'where clause'"

Tags: mysql, sql, join, subquery, mysql-5.6

First off, take a look at diagram (this is an application for testing students knowledge)

[image: Tables diagram]

I already have working application, which calculates score (in percents), but to sort by score, it is required to select all the records (of current test). And it drastically slows down app (~ 10 seconds of waiting). So I decided to move that logic into single sql query.

Now, my SQL query looks like this:

```sql
select test_results.*,
       (
           select test_result_total_score * 100 / test_result_total_max_score
           from (
                    select (select sum(question_score)
                            from (
                                     select question_total_right_answers = question_total_options as question_score
                                     from (
                                              select (
                                                         select count(*)
                                                         from answers
                                                                  inner join answer_options on answer_options.id = answers.answer_option_id
                                                         where answers.asked_question_id = asked_questions.id
                                                           and answers.is_chosen = answer_options.is_right
                                                     ) as question_total_right_answers,
                                                     (
                                                         select count(*)
                                                         from answers
                                                                  left join answer_options on answer_options.id = answers.answer_option_id
                                                         where answers.asked_question_id = asked_questions.id
                                                     ) as question_total_options
                                              from asked_questions
                                              where asked_questions.test_result_id = test_results.id
                                          ) as rigt_per_question
                                 ) as questions_scores)                             as test_result_total_score,
                           (select count(*)
                            from asked_questions
                            where asked_questions.test_result_id = test_results.id) as test_result_total_max_score
                ) as right_per_test_result
       ) as result_in_percents
from test_results
where test_results.id between 1 and 200;
```

Here is what it should do: for each asked question collect how many answer options there are (`question_total_options`) and how many answers user selected right (`question_total_right_answers`) - the very nested subqueries.
Then for each of this results calculate `score` (this is basically 1 if user selected all right options and 0 if at least one option is selected not right).
After that, we sum `scores` of all that questions (`test_result_total_score` - how many questions user answered right). Also, we calculate how many questions there are in test result (`test_result_total_max_score`).
With that information we can calculate percentage of right answered questions (`test_result_total_score * 100 / test_result_total_max_score`)

And the error is on lines 23 and 28:

```sql
where asked_questions.test_result_id = test_results.id
```

```sql
where asked_questions.test_result_id = test_results.id) as test_result_total_max_score
```

It says: `[42S22][1054] Unknown column 'test_results.id' in 'where clause'`

I have tried using variable `@test_result_id` like this:

```sql
select test_results.*,
       @test_result_id := test_results.id,
       ( ... )
```

```sql
where asked_questions.test_result_id = @test_result_id
```

```sql
where asked_questions.test_result_id = @test_result_id) as test_result_total_max_score
```

And it evaluates, but in wrong way (probably because order of evaluation select values is undefined). BTW, all `result_in_percents` correspond to very first result.

[image: results when use variable]

Comment: My guess is that your current query can be written in a more simpler way.  Including sample data in your question would help with that.

Comment: As already stated, this query is pretty rough. I'd bet you can do this without any subqueries, but we'll need some sample data to make sure it's working as intended.

Comment: A subquery can only refer to tables in the immediately containing query. You're trying to refer to `test_results.id` in queries nested about 3 levels deep.

Answer (score 0):

For those facing similar problem, it seems that there is no simple solution.
First off, you can try rewrite your subqueries with joins as I did (see below). But when you would like to perform group operations on grouped results, you are really unhappy person). A "dirty" solution might be create function to overcome barrier of nesting subqueries.

```sql
create function test_result_in_percents(test_result_id bigint unsigned)
    returns float
begin
    return (
        select sum(tmp.question_right) * 100 / count(*)
        from (select sum(answers.is_chosen = answer_options.is_right) = count(*) as question_right
                   , asked_questions.test_result_id                              as test_result_id
              from answers
                       inner join answer_options on answer_options.id = answers.answer_option_id
                       inner join asked_questions on asked_questions.id = answers.asked_question_id
              where asked_questions.test_result_id = test_result_id
              group by answers.asked_question_id
             ) as tmp
        group by test_result_id
    );
end;
```

And then, just use this function:

```sql
select (test_result_in_percents(test_results.id)) as `result_percents`
from `test_results`
where `test_results`.`test_id` = 181
  and `test_results`.`test_id` is not null
order by `test_results`.`id` desc;
```